# Adding Flask app in existing nginx PHP configuration

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, flask

The configuration below is the configuration for a web application in PHP, and it's working (I faked the site's name to https://sub.mysite.nl).

```
server {
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

        ## some certificate info ##

        root /path/to/www;
        index index.php index.htm index.html;

        server_name sub.mysite.nl;

        location / {
                try_files               $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files               $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index           index.php;
                fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include                 fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }

        ## some logging info ##

    }

server {
        if ($host = sub.mysite.nl) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;

        server_name sub.mysite.nl;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Now I want to add a Flask app in a subfolder e.g. https://sub.mysite.nl/flaskapp.

The block below is what I got from the Flask Mega Tutorial I followed, see specifically this chapter: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux (under Setting Up Nginx). I think I need to put this under `location /flaskapp/` but I'm not sure how to proceed, because when I do this and go to https://sub.mysite.com/flaskapp it gives me `404 Not Found`.

```
    location /flaskapp {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Do I need to change the routing in my Flask app?

Comment: set the location block over the "location /" one, and change it to "location ~ ^flaskapp {}". Do you have any log on your flask app to see if the connection gets there but can't find it, or it directly don't enter the flaskapp and the 404 is given by another one?

Comment: The URIs `/flaskapp` and `/flaskapp/` are not the same. Does your flask application respond with the trailing `/` appended?

Comment: Ok first of all, I made a stupid mistake by including the wrong file in nginx.conf but now I edited that and it gives the Flask 404 page instead of the browser's 404 page. @flaixman do you mean "above" or "around" when you say "over"? If I put it on top, the php app stops working and I get the browser's 404 again.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks, I edited my post. See my above comment: I get a Flask 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've been fooling around a bit and it seems like editing the routes in my Flask app provides the easiest solution. For this, I use the Flask nginx block from my original post at the bottom.

So instead of `@app.route('/')`, I use `@app.route('/flaskapp/')`.

And `@app.route('/view_profile/<username>')` becomes `@app.route('/flaskapp/view_profile/<username>')`.